# Saturating arithmetic issues with warnings

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have to create two functions that add together unsigned/signed numbers. However, the compiler is giving me the following warnings, and the implementations don't seem to work correctly (as it stalls). I believe there might be an error in logic here, not something else that is semantic which is throwing me off. I am new to this and would appreciate any insight.

Warnings:

- comparison is always false due to limited range of data type; // this is in the first function, comparison lines
- large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type; // again, first function, comparison lines
- overflow in implicit constant conversion; // if statements in bottom function

Both functions take parameters a and b. Here is the unsigned one:

```
    unsigntype result = a + b;
    if (result < INT_MIN) result = INT_MIN;
    if (result > INT_MAX) result = INT_MAX;
    return result;
```

And the signed one:

```
    signtype result = a + b;
    signtype check = result;
    signtype position = 0;

    while (check >>= 0)
            position++; // get sig fig

    if ((1 << (position + 1)) && result != 0) {
            if ((a > 0 && b > 0)) return INT_MAX;
            return result;
    }

    if ((a < 0 && b < 0) && result > 0) return INT_MIN;
    return result;
```

EDIT: The typedefs you see here are placeholders that can be filled by any integer family type defined by a header file that is included.

ANOTHER EDIT: This controls which type should be used. Both functions have to be completely portable - can use bitwise operations.

```
#ifndef SAT_TYPE
#define SAT_TYPE 1
#endif

#if SAT_TYPE == 1
typedef signed char signtype;
typedef unsigned char unsigntype;
#define FMT "hh"
#elif SAT_TYPE == 2
typedef signed short signtype;
typedef unsigned short unsigntype;
#define FMT "h"
#elif SAT_TYPE == 3
typedef signed int signtype;
typedef unsigned int unsigntype;
#define FMT ""
```

Comment: On what lines do the warnings appear?

Comment: Can you post some compilable code? >>`unsigntype`?

Comment: What is `unsigntype` and `signtype`?

Comment: I have added more information now.

Comment: Please make it _compilable_ though - it would be helpful to see the types of `a` and `b` at least.

Comment: @Useless These functions are supposed to work so that any type (signed/unsigned char, short, int, long and long long) should replace these placeholders

Comment: So are they macros? Are `a` and `b` the same type as the result? Please show what the actual code (function, macro, whatever) should look like, not just a snippet with no context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unsigned case:

```
unsigntype result = a + b;
if (result < INT_MIN) result = INT_MIN;
```

`INT_MIN` is *negative* but an unsigned type can never be less than zero, so this test is indeed always false. In the next line

```
if (result > INT_MAX) result = INT_MAX;
```

you still haven't said what `unsigntype` is, but if it can't hold a value bigger than INT_MAX (for example, if it's an `unsigned short` or `unsigned char`) then this will also be always false. Ideally you should be using the correct max and min for your actual type, eg.

```
unsigned short add_ushort(unsigned short a, unsigned short b) {
  if (a > USHRT_MAX - b) return USHRT_MAX;
  return a+b;
}
```

Note that I'm ignoring the negative check, because that's impossible here (you didn't say what type `a` and `b` are, so I can't tell if they might be negative in your case), and I wrote an overflow check that actually works.

---

As for the signed case, I'm not even certain what you're trying to achieve. You have an infinite loop here:

```
while (check != 0)
        position++; // doesn't change check, so never exits
```

and the rest looks .. puzzling. Perhaps you could show the expected results for some inputs?

---

Now you've described the setup, I'd suggest defining the type-specific max/min values in your existing pre-processor code:

```
#if SAT_TYPE == 1
typedef signed char signtype;
typedef unsigned char unsigntype;
#define SIGN_MAX CHAR_MAX
#define SIGN_MIN CHAR_MIN
#define UNSIGN_MAX UCHAR_MAX
#define FMT "hh"
#else
/* ... */
#endif

unsigntype add_unsigned(unsigntype a, unsigntype b) {
  // NB. you need to check for overflow before adding:
  // after the sum has overflowed, it's too late
  if (a > UNSIGN_MAX - b) return UNSIGN_MAX;
  return a+b;
}

signtype add_signed(signtype a, signtype b) {
  if (b < 0 && a < SIGN_MIN - b) return SIGN_MIN;
  if (b > 0 && a > SIGN_MAX - b) return SIGN_MAX;
  return a+b;
}
```

Comment: Okay, in response to the unsigned case, we have to return "sticky" values but keep the function independent of a particular type. I'm not sure how to do this, I guess which is why I used INT_MIN, etc., but I see now why that wouldn't work. In response to the signed case, that should be while (check >>= 1) to get at the first sig fig. Then I try and check whether that is positive or negative. The other checks are to determine whether both the added values are of the same sign, and if the result is of the opposite sign, it overflows.

Comment: Also, I see you're doing only one check in the unsigned function. What about if the function overflows the other way? Why only check USHRT_MAX. I am new to this, so any explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you add two positive numbers, the result must be positive. Unsigned numbers cannot be negative, so the result cannot be negative, and you don't need to check for it. This is why the type of `a` and `b` matters though, and you still haven't said what it is.

Comment: Right, that makes sense - completely forgot about that property of unsigned numbers. I've edited the question above with more information as well. Also, to find the maximum, couldn't you just do sizeof(type)?

Comment: No trouble. FWIW, if you have the freedom to use C++ at any point in the future, you can do this much more cleanly with function templates.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess, but I'm guessing that you will get one of the warnings on this line:

```
if (result < INT_MIN) result = INT_MIN;
```

Why? Because `result` is an unsigned type (I'm assuming) and `INT_MIN` (assuming you use the [standard `INT_MIN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)) is a negative number. Since `result` can never be less that zero, checking if it's less than a negative number will always be false.

Also, if `unsigntype` is a type smaller than `int`, then `result` will never be larger than `INT_MAX` either. That comparison only makes sense if the type is equal or larger than `unsigned int` and you want to limit the variables value to little more then e.g. 2 billion (on a system where `int` is 32 bits).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (result < INT_MIN) result = INT_MIN;
```

The test is comparing a signed int with an unsigned int quantity. So
 is promoted to unsigned int. Interpreting a negative as an unsigned int yields a big positive
number, making the clause false.

Take a look to *Deep C Secrets*: [A subtle bug](http://books.google.es/books?id=9f9uAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22Even+though+the+rules+were+changed,+subtle+bugs%22&hl=es&sa=X&ei=fC3OU6SaA86R0QWy8oHQBA&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Even%20though%20the%20rules%20were%20changed%2C%20subtle%20bugs%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

In the unsigned case, this is amusing:

```
result = a + b ;
if (result < a)
  result = -1 ;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I grant you this is not a complete solution: I cannot add to the suggestions for signed -- 'cos I don't think you can do it without knowing the min/max for the signed type in question.  The above, however will add two unsigned integers of some named unsigned type, and clamp the result to the maximum for that type (which is my understanding of unsigned saturating addition) -- without needing to know the unsigned range of the type.  If that's not at least part of what the OP needed, then I apologise.